# Using gnuplot to create data files

Tags: plot, terminal, ascii, gnuplot

Hey guys I am currently working with gnuplot.
I have this .csv file which I have been using to plot some formulas 
(eg `plot "filename.csv" u 0:day($0) = $0` ). The plots worked out; however, I was wondering if there was a way within gnuplot to save the output of my formulas as a data file too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check the manual or in the gnuplot console type `help table`.

**Code:**

```
### save data as text
reset session

f(x) = x
g(x) = x**2
h(x) = x**3

set xrange[-5:5]
set samples 11

plot f(x) w lp, g(x) w lp, h(x) w lp

set table "myOutput.dat"
    plot '+' u 1:(f($1)):(g($1)):(h($1)) w table
unset table

### end of code
```

**Edit**:

Actually, to be more flexible with data separators (e.g. comma or whatever) in the output file, you could change the `plot ... w table` command to something like the line below. However, I guess, gnuplot will always add a leading space `" "` and a trailing TAB `\t` for each line. But maybe this can also be changed.

```
plot '+' u (sprintf("%g,%g,%g,%g",$1,f($1),g($1),h($1))) w table
```

**Result:**

[image]

And `myOutput.dat`:

```
 -5  -5  25  -125
 -4  -4  16  -64
 -3  -3  9   -27
 -2  -2  4   -8
 -1  -1  1   -1
 0   0   0   0
 1   1   1   1
 2   2   4   8
 3   3   9   27
 4   4   16  64
 5   5   25  125
```

**Addition:** (creating data in a loop)

With `set print` you are probably the most flexible, no leading space and trailing TAB.
Check the manual or in gnuplot console type `help set print`.

**Code:**

```
### save data as text, independent of range and samples
reset session

f(x) = x
g(x) = x**2
h(x) = x**3

set print "myOutput.dat"
    do for [i=-5:5] {   
        # loop index only takes integers, multiply i with some factor if necessary
        print sprintf("%g,%g,%g,%g",i,f(i),g(i),h(i))
    }
set print
### end of code
```

Comment: Is there a way to creating them without calling the plot command?

Comment: of course you can skip the line `plot f(x) w lp, g(x) w lp, h(x) w lp`, but you need the line `plot '+' u 1:(f($1)):(g($1)):(h($1)) w table`. Well, there is another way to print into a file during a for loop, this might even be more clear. I will add this option later. In the meantime you might want to check `help set print`.